# Java - Storing Mixed Types (Arrays, Internal Tables)

Tags: java

This is my first post and I promise that I've search quite a bit on this subject. I'm not a Java wiz by any stretch of the imagination, so I maybe just not understanding how what I want to achieve is now represented.

I come from an old IBM/AS400 + ABAP and some occasional Delphi programming background.

What I need to achieve is internally store approximately 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 rows with about 50 columns. I need to perform a whole bunch of mathematical equations on these values so accessing a database is not an option.

Most of the 50 columns will be integer or indicator values, but the primary key will be a date value (Not that Java appears to do dates that well :) ).

So from my earlier programming days the terms "Arrays" (IBM) and Internal Tables (SAP ABAP) are what I'm used to.

But for Java via Eclipse I'm seeing a whole bunch of stuff that I'm really not that familiar with. ArrayList, Treemaps, Objects, I've played around with a few of these, but I just might not be doing it right.

Therefore Gurus, what is the best mechanism to use in this scenario. Considering the volume it needs to perform well.

Many Thanks in advance

Panduranga

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider to use some kind of database unless your target system provides a lot of RAM and to pick a different primary key (or use date in millis after 1970-01-01 instead).

For your given example I will use 64bit memory for each column:

64bit * 50 * 10,000,000 = 32000000000 bit
~3,72 GiB

Then start with a simple class to hold those 50 columns:

```
public class MyEntity {
    public long index;
    public long value;
    ...
}
```

To store them you can use a Map (use Date as index only if you must):

```
Map<Date, MyEntity> mapEntities = new HashMap<Date, MyEntity>();
```

If you decide to store all objects in RAM you will have to adjust memory of Java-VM (>4g for your case):

```
java -Xmx4g
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Decide on the indexing method you need. By what criterias are you going to select specific rows from that table? Would they be sequential (just processing row after row)? Would you need to jump randomly among rows by some criteria (for example, depending on intermediate result of some formula)?
2. Given the answer to the 1st question, you can decide which data structure is best for you. Some examples:

   - There are child rows and parent rows? Some kind of graph or tree would probably be the best.
   - Querying criteria is complex, and subject to change? Consider using a SQL-enabled database.
   - You need to frequently select values based on values of several columns or their derivative calculations? Consider indexing into some kind of Map. Maybe even multiple times, to build different indexes.
   - You need to just go through all rows and make some calculation for each? Any kind of List would work.

Etc.